# 要素が配列に含まれているかどうか調べる時に、要素, 配列の順番に書けるような書き方はありますか？

Tags: ruby

Rubyについての質問です。
要素が配列に含まれているかどうか調べる時に、要素, 配列の順番に書けるような書き方はありますか？

具体的には

```rb
if [:dog, :cat, :monkey].include? :monkey
  puts "banana"
end
```

の代わりに、

```rb
if (:monkey).is_in [:dog, :cat, :monkey]
  puts "banana"
end
```

みたいな書き方です。いい方法があったら教えてください。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

もし、ActiveSupport がある環境であれば `Object#in?` が使えます。

```rb
:monkey.in? [:dog, :cat, :monkey]
=> true
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.12/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/inclusion.rb#L13

Answer (score 2):

Object クラスに `is_in` メソッドを追加するという方法もあります。

```
class Object
  def is_in(arg)
    arg.include?(self)
  end
end
```

```
if (:monkey).is_in [:dog, :cat, :monkey]
  puts "banana"
end
=> banana

"or".is_in "Hello World"
=> true
```